# Broken INTERNAL link internal_error.html

Tags: django, url, hyperlink, internal

I keep getting emails from django about broken INTERNAL links.

They're always point to internal_error.html. Although no error is shown.

Anyone know how I can get to the bottom of these errors?

Here's an example email:

> Referrer:
>   http://www.example.com/subject/590/Philosophy/
>
> Requested URL:/subject//internal_error.html
>
> User agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:2.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0
>
> IP address: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

Comment: Also, they seem to be hard to reproduce. Sometimes I get this error if I request a page but if I try again it'll work.

Comment: I'm running this on Passenger. Could that be the problem if the server is killing processes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I contacted my host and they said that

> your scripts have been getting
>   automatically killed by our Process
>   Watcher script due to your sites going
>   over Memory limits on the shared
>   server.

:(

Answer (score 0):

Are you using fastcgi?

It seems, that this problem accures with very big or long apges, as written in [one of the topics](http://www.mail-archive.com/django-users@googlegroups.com/msg00505.html). One of the users said, that enabling gzip helped.

django-fcgi.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from flup.server.fcgi_fork import WSGIServer
#from flup.server.fcgi import WSGIServer
from flup.middleware.gzip import GzipMiddleware

from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler

handler = WSGIHandler()
handler = GzipMiddleware(handler)
WSGIServer(handler).run()
```